# UI grid does not update

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have read all the previous questions, tried several solutions but still my grid won't update. It loads all the data correctly. But if I try to add data, the grid doesn't update. I have a simple test button to add data, however, The alert get's shown but the grid doesnt update.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', 'Auth', '$modal', 'scrapeAPI', '$http',  'uiGridConstants', '$alert', 'recommendationsAPI', 'Upload'];

  function MainCtrl($scope, $state, Auth, $modal, uiGridConstants, scrapeAPI, $http, $alert, recommendationsAPI, Upload) {
    $scope.user = Auth.getCurrentUser();

    $scope.recommendation = {};
    $scope.recommendations = [];
    $scope.recommendationPostForm = true;
    $scope.busy = true;
    $scope.allData = [];

    //get data from server
    recommendationsAPI.getAllRecommendations()
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log('looks found ');
        console.log(data);
        $scope.recommendations = data.data;
        $scope.allData = data.data;
        // $scope.nextPage();
        $scope.busy = false;
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('failed to get looks ' + err);
      });


    $scope.addData = function() {
    var n = $scope.recommendationgrid.data.length + 1;
    alert (n);
    $scope.recommendations.data.push ({
                "recommendation": "abc",
              });           
    };

    // Hier wordt de grid opgebouwd met all informatie. 
    $scope.recommendationgrid = {
    showGridFooter: true,
    showColumnFooter: false,
    enableFiltering: false,
    columnDefs: [
        { field: 'recommendation'},

    ],
    data: 'recommendations',
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
};

  }
})();
```

Comment: any console error messages ?

Answer (score 0):

I see here you're checking the length of `$scope.recommendationgrid.data` and then adding data to `$scope.recommendations.data`.

Below that, you have `$scope.recommendationgrid` that has `data` pointing to a string:

`data: 'recommendations'`

Comment: OK but what should i change iT to?

Answer (score 0):

Have you injected the `ui.grid` module properly as shown below ?

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ui.grid'])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);
```

After that check here also... `data: 'recommendations',` need to set it as shown below.

```
 $scope.recommendationgrid = {
    showGridFooter: true,
    showColumnFooter: false,
    enableFiltering: false,
    columnDefs: [
        { field: 'recommendation'},

    ],
    data:  $scope.recommendations.data,
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
};
```